# Case statement error - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, series

I have the code below that runs some calculations on Xvar - which is a single series with numeric data. It basically performs simpleaction comparing previous value in that series (via shift) to current value using case ifs to populate the variable Z. So for the first if statement says if both the current and previous values are both zero then just set Z to 0 for that output.  I did this in excel successfully without any issues but in Python the code generates the ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). So I revised the code addiing in any() command (see version "code2 revised". This fixes the error but does not give me the results I was expecting. It seem ignore all the criteria in the if statament and just runs the last line on every data point giving me incorrect results : `"else: Z = (Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)) / Xvar.shift(-1) *np.sign (Xvar.shift(-1))"`

```
Xvar = okdata.testvariable
Xvar.astype(float)
#code 1 version 
for i in Xvar:  
     if (Xvar==0 and Xvar.shift(-1) ==0):   Z = 0
     elif (Xvar >0 and Xvar.shift(-1) <0):  Z = ((Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1))/Xvar.shift(-1)) * SIGN (Xvar.shift(-1))
     elif(Xvar >0 and Xvar.shift(-1) ==0): Z = Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)
     elif(Xvar <0 and Xvar.shift(-1) <0):  Z = (Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)) /Xvar.shift(-1)*SIGN(Xvar.shift(-1))
     elif(Xvar ==0 and Xvar.shift(-1)<0):  Z = (Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)) /Xvar.shift(-1)*SIGN(Xvar.shift(-1))
     elif(Xvar <0 and Xvar.shift(-1) ==0): Z = Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)
     else:                                 Z = (Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)) / Xvar.shift(-1)
```

#code2 - revised - adds in any()

```
for i in Xvar:  
     if (Xvar.any()==0 and Xvar.shift(-1).any() ==0):  Z = 0
     elif (Xvar.any() >0 and Xvar.shift(-1).any() <0): Z = ((Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1))/Xvar.shift(-1)) * np.sign(Xvar.shift(-1))
     elif(Xvar.any() >0 and Xvar.shift(-1).any() ==0): Z = Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)
     elif(Xvar.any() <0 and Xvar.shift(-1).any() <0):  Z = (Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)) /Xvar.shift(-1)*np.sign(Xvar.shift(-1))
     elif(Xvar.any() ==0 and Xvar.shift(-1).any() <0): Z = (Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)) /Xvar.shift(-1)*np.sign(Xvar.shift(-1))
     elif(Xvar.any() <0 and Xvar.shift(-1).any() ==0): Z = Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)
     else:                                             Z = (Xvar - Xvar.shift(-1)) / Xvar.shift(-1) *np.sign (Xvar.shift(-1))
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `numpy`, it would be easier to do what you need using `numpy.select`:

```
diff = Xvar.sub(Xvar.shift(-1))
changes = diff.div(Xvar.shift(-1)).mul(np.sign(Xvar.shift(-1)))

conditions = [Xvar.eq(0) & Xvar.shift(-1).eq(0),
              (Xvar.gt(0) & Xvar.shift(-1).eq(0)) | (Xvar.lt(0) & Xvar.shift(-1).eq(0)), 
              ]

choices = [0, diff]

Z = np.select(conditions, choices, changes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach. Running this code generates the following error: ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions.

Comment: @user155415 - Apologies. I’ve edited the answer.